# How to permanently allow use of port 81?

Tags: nginx, vps

I am using a VPS on nginx ubuntu and I am hosting two different files on default port (80) and the port 81.

The problem is that I ALWAYS have to run this command below before making the port 81 useable

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 81 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

So if the VPS reboot I would no be able to access the server that is hosted on 81.

If someone could help me with that, thank you :)

Comment: Your VPS provider may be enforcing some iptables settings. See if the provider's VPS management interface has any firewall settings to configure: if it has, use it as your primary firewall configuration tool as it may override anything else on VPS restart.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply by using the following command after adding the rule:

```
sudo iptables-save
```

That will make sure that it's permanent and doesn't need to be done each time the machine is rebooted.

Comment: Sorry this does not work, when I reboot the server I have to add the same line that I wrote in my post

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this goal in different ways.

**Please check which tool is used in your VPS to configure the firewall**. Search the VPS providers documentation on how to configure the firewall, in case it is not clear.

Firewall management could be accomplished in the VPS portal somtimes, or could be configured in the VPS directly, via scripts or programs.

In case it is configured on the VPS itself:

The default firewall configuration tool for Ubuntu is ufw.
To see the status, enter: `sudo ufw status`.
**In case ufw is used**, the command to allow port 81 is `sudo ufw allow 81`.

Another possibility could be `iptables-save` - this saves the current firewall rules, which can be used to load the rules after a server has been restarted. A nice article which explains the usage: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-save-iptables-firewall-rules-permanently-on-linux/
In order to automate the process, install iptables-persistent package: `sudo apt install iptables-persistent`.

Comment: Unfortunately the sudo ufw satus does not work, I have to use the command I wrote on my post once I reload the server